# Triggering tasks on Semver change: triggers jobs out or order

Tags: concourse, concourse-git-resource

Here's what I'm trying to achieve:

I have a project with a build job for a binary release. The binary takes a while to cross-compile for each platform, so I only want to release build to be done when a release is tagged, but I want the local-native version to build and tests to run for each checked-in version.

Based on the flight-school demo... so far, my pipeline configuration looks like this:

```
resources:
  - name: flight-school
    type: git
    source:
      uri: https://github.com/nbering/flight-school
      branch: master

  - name: flight-school-version
    type: semver
    source:
      driver: git
      uri: https://github.com/nbering/flight-school
      branch: master
      file: version

jobs:
  - name: test-app
    plan:
      - get: flight-school
        trigger: true
      - task: tests
        file: flight-school/build.yml

  - name: release-build
    plan:
      - aggregate:
        - get: flight-school-version
          trigger: true
        - get: flight-school
          passed: [test-app]
      - task: release-build
        file: flight-school/ci/release.yml
```

This produces a pipeline in the Web UI that looks like this:

[image: Concourse Pipeline Sample]

The problem is that when I update the "release" file in the git repository, the semver resource, "flight-school-version" can check before the git resource "flight-school", causing the release build to be processed from the git version assigned to the previous check-in.

I'd like a way to work around this so that the release build appears as a separate task, but only triggers when the version is bumped.

#### Some things I've thought of so far

Create a separate git resource with a `tag_filter` set so that it only runs when a semver tag has been push to master

- Pro: Jobs only run when tag is pushed
- Con: Has the same disconnected-inheritance problem for tests as the semver-based example above

Add the conditional check for a semver tag (or change diff on a file) using the git history in the checkout as part of the build script

- Pro: Will do basically what I want without too much wrestling with Concourse
- Con: Can't see the difference in the UI without actually reading the build output
- Con: Difficult to compose with other tasks and resource types to do something with the binary release

Manually trigger release build

- Pro: Simple to set up
- Con: Requires manual intervention.

Use the API to trigger a paused build step on completion of tests when a version change is detected

- Con: Haven't seen any examples of others doing this, seems really complicated.

I haven't found a way to trigger a task when *both* the git resource and semver resource change.

I'm looking for either an answer to solve the concurrency problem in my above example, or an alternative pattern that would produce a similar release workflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Summary

Here's what I came up with for a solution, based on suggestions from the Concourse CI slack channel.

I added a parallel "release" track, which filters on tags resembling a [semantic versioning](https://semver.org) versions. The two tracks share task configuration files and build scripts.

## Tag Filtering

The [git](https://github.com/concourse/git-resource) resource supports a `tag_filter` option. From the README:

> `tag_filter`: *Optional.* If specified, the resource will only detect commits
>     that have a tag matching the expression that have been made against
>     the `branch`. Patterns are [glob(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/glob.7.html)
>     compatible (as in, bash compatible).

I used a simple glob pattern to match my semver tags (like `v0.0.1`):

```
v[0-9]*
```

At first I tried an "extglob" pattern, matching semantic versions exactly, like this:

```
v+([0-9]).+([0-9]).+([0-9])?(\-+([-A-Za-z0-9.]))?(\++([-A-Za-z0-9.]))
```

That didn't work, because the git resource isn't using the `extglob` shell option.

The end result is a resource that looks like this:

```
resource:
  - name: flight-school-release
    type: git
    source:
      uri: https://github.com/nbering/flight-school
      branch: master
      tag_filter: 'v[0-9]*'
```

## Re-Using Task Definitions

The next challenge I faced was avoiding re-writing my test definition file for the release track. I would have to do this because all the file paths use the resource name, and I now have a resource for release, and development. My solution is to override the resource with an option on the get task.

```
jobs:
  - name: test-app-release
    plan:
      - get: flight-school
        resource: flight-school-release
        trigger: true
      - task: tests
        file: flight-school/build.yml
```

Build.yml above is the standard example from the [flight school](https://concourse.ci/flight-school.html) tutorial.

## Putting It All Together

My resulting pipeline looks like this:

[image: Concourse Pipeline with Parallel Tracks]

My complete pipeline config looks like this:

```
resources:
  - name: flight-school-master
    type: git
    source:
      uri: https://github.com/nbering/flight-school
      branch: master

  - name: flight-school-release
    type: git
    source:
      uri: https://github.com/nbering/flight-school
      branch: master
      tag_filter: 'v[0-9]*'

jobs:
  - name: test-app-dev
    plan:
      - get: flight-school
        resource: flight-school-master
        trigger: true
      - task: tests
        file: flight-school/build.yml

  - name: test-app-release
    plan:
      - get: flight-school
        resource: flight-school-release
        trigger: true
      - task: tests
        file: flight-school/build.yml

  - name: build-release
    plan:
      - get: flight-school
        resource: flight-school-release
        trigger: true
        passed: [test-app-release]
      - task: release-build
        file: flight-school/ci/release.yml
```

Comment: You should check out Concourse CI's upcoming feature... https://github.com/concourse/concourse/issues/1707

Comment: @DwayneForde I’ll watch the changelog for this new feature. When it hits, I’ll try to update my pipeline to use it, and if it works out, I’ll update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you should manually click the `release-build` button, and let everything else be automated. I'm assuming you are manually bumping your version number, but it seems better to move that manual intervention to releasing.

What I would do is have put at the end of `release-build` that bumps your minor version. Something like:

```
- put: flight-school-version
  params:
    bump: minor
```

That way you will always be on the correct version, once you release `0.0.1`, you are done with it forever, you can only go forward.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. At the suggestion of someone in the Concourse CI slack channel, I think I'm going to settle on having a parallel chain of jobs, running on master, and filtered on Semver-formatted tags. I was hoping to avoid this since it requires copy-paste type repetition of jobs and resources, but it seems to fit my workflow best. I'll probably abandon the semver resource entirely. I'll update with an answer for how I do it once I've implemented an example with flight-school.